# Estimating $n$ column norms of $A$ by using less than $n$ calls to $Ax$?

Tags: approximation

Suppose I have an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ that is only accessible through matrix-vector products $Ax$. These are expensive, is there a way to approximate vector $x$ of $n$ column norms of $A$ by using less than $n$ calls to the matrix-vector product?

$$
\begin{aligned}a_{1}=\left[ A\right] \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\a_{2}=\left[ A\right] \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\a_{3}=\left[ A\right] \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
x=\langle\left\| a_{1}\right\|,\left\| a_{2}\right\|,\left\| a_{3}\right\| \rangle\end{aligned}
$$

Note that I can estimate a vector of *row* norms by sampling a few random vectors $y$ from standard normal, vector of row norms squared is proportional to entries of $E[(Ay) \odot (Ay)]$

**Edit** random idea, if we let $y_{1,2}^T=\langle y_1, y_2\rangle$ with $E[y_{1,2} y_{1,2}^T]=I$ and $\hat{y}_{1,2}^T=\langle y_1, y_2, 0, 0, \ldots\rangle$ then

$$ E[\|A\hat{y}\|^2]=\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr} E \Tr [(A\hat{y})(A\hat{y})^T]=\|a_1\|^2+\|a_2\|^2=t_{1,2}$$

Perhaps there's a strategy of choosing a good collection of overlapping subsets $\{s_1,s_2,\ldots\}$ such that $\{\|a_1\|^2,\|a_2\|^2,\ldots\}$ could be recovered from corresponding totals $\{t_{s_1},t_{s_2},\ldots\}$